# 16mb limit Mongodb : Alternative

Tags: mongodb

I have been using MongoDB since sometime in production and lately have come across the limitation of it i.e. 16mb size per document. In reality this should not be a problem since 16mb is way too much for anything especially text data. But here I am dealing with the insurance domain where in the data is more complex and it can have many nested documents inside a main document that can exceed the 16mb limit.
I know that I can use GridFS to store the bigger files, but I am dealing with only text here with complex data, not any images/videos etc.

Can anyone please suggest something? Any other alternative? Or how I can overcome this 16mb limit?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as mongodb is concerned, you can redesign your schema to make things better. What you should do, is **analyze your application's data access patterns**. On the basis of that design your schema.

If you do the analysis, you might find that there's only some fields of the embedded/nested documents, that you want for a particular view. In that case you case embed only those fields in your parent document and can create a separate collection for other fields including the fields that you have embedded in the parent document.

What I would strongly recommend is for you to read [this blog post by MongoDB on schema design](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1). This will help you realize if there's something that can be done with the documents in your collection. I would also encourage you to read the part2 and three as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will definitely go through that blog. I did think to put the nested documents into another collection, but the reads/updates/writes would become slower right. So went with nested documents approach.

Comment: Yeah but then that's the tradeff you'll have to bear. That's why I suggested you to **embed only some fields which are accessed on your application screens**. Analyze your application's data access patterns.

For eg : IF you have an event collection and a videos collection, and there's a screen in your application that shows event details along with the Name, and link to your video, then you can embed the name, link and _id of the video in your events collection and can put rest of the fields including there fields in a separate collection like video release date, video playback time, etc

Comment: Yeah right. We will do that. Just wanted to avoid the tradeoff. So wanted to know if there are any alternatives!!!